# Clarify the Firebase connections

Tags: android, ios, firebase

I am a little confused about the Firebase pricing model, special concern is the connections or more precisely concurrent connections.

Let's have an example of a mobile app for iOS called FanZONE:

*User will create groups during football matches. They will comment on the actual game and the comments are immediately displayed on each members screen.*

Does this scenario means that each user who is participating on commenting/viewing counts for one connection?
So if a group contains 100 users who actively follow the screen and from time to time comment is there 100 connections each 90 minutes long?
What about users who have the app in the background and the app checks each 5 minutes the score. Is this connection as well 90 minutes long or only a fraction of time every 5 minutes?

Comment: As I read in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/rtdb-vs-firestore) Now days Realtime Database: "Scale to around 200,000 concurrent connections and 1,000 writes/second in a single database. Scaling beyond that requires sharding your data across multiple databases."

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In your first scenario - the short answer is yes. As long as your users keep the screen on where you have a Firebase connection that allows them to comment/read comments - you will have one concurrent connection per screen.

In your second scenario - this depends on how you develop your app. The Firebase API does provide you with the **goOffline** and **goOnline** methods (https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios-api/Classes/Firebase.html#class_methods) which give you control over your connection. If you want to go offline for 5 minutes, then briefly come back online to check scores and then go offline again, then you'd only hold a connection for a short duration.

Concurrent connections are just that - connections established at the same time. So if you have 3 people using your app to check scores, but user 1's app goes online at 12:00 PM and the connection lasts for 5 seconds, then user 2's app goes online at 12:01 PM for 5 seconds, and user 3's app goes online at 12:02 PM for 5 seconds then you've only ever had 1 concurrent connection.

If on the other hand, all 3 users' apps go online at 12:00 PM for 5 seconds then you'll have 3 concurrent connections.

You could potentially use this same goOffline/goOnline strategy with your first scenario, but that may detract from the experience if your users are expecting to be chatting about a game in near real-time.

Comment: thanks, that's pretty much clears most of my issues. goOffline goOnline can be used for most of the scenarios to save the connections  for larger userbase.

Comment: without willing to go off-subject, I guess this means that firebase is socket-based (rather than AJAX based)?

Comment: It is only me on a simulator and it shows me I have 8 connections. How come?

Comment: Excellent technique explained to use more than 100 connection with Firebase free plan!

Answer (score 79):

In addition to Mike P's excellent answer, here are a few other discussions on the same topic which may prove insightful.

From the Firebase [pricing page](https://www.firebase.com/pricing.html):

> **What is a Connection?**
>
> A connection is an open network connection to our servers. It's a
>   measure of the number of users that are using your app or site
>   simultaneously. This isn't the same as (and is usually a lot lower
>   than) the total number of visitors to your site or the total number of
>   users of your app. In our experience, 1 concurrent corresponds to
>   roughly 1,400 monthly visits.
>
> Our Development Firebase has a hard limit on the number of connections
>   allowed. All of the paid Firebases, however, are “burstable”, which
>   means usage is not capped and instead you are billed for any overages.
>   We measure connections for paid plans based on the 95th percentile of
>   usage during the month.

From [this mailing list discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/njlkmHQr5No), by Andrew Lee (Firebase founder):

> I strongly recommend you not worry about it unless you're actually
>   bumping up against our limits...most developers vastly overestimate the number of
>   concurrent users they will have. A good rule of thumb is 1 concurrent
>   = 1000 monthly visits for the typical website. For mobile, the ratio between installs and concurrents is sometimes even higher (though it
>   varies considerably depending on your use case). Our plans are quite
>   generous when it comes to concurrent users. As a data point -- our own
>   website could operate comfortably on the "free" Firebase plan most
>   days. In fact, more than 99.5% of all of Firebases never hit the 50
>   concurrent limit.
>
> So, long story short, if you're working on a hobby project, you will
>   almost certainly not hit our free tier 50-concurrent limit. If you're
>   a business or a larger app, I hope you will find our $49 / month plan
>   more cost-effective than spending engineering time to figure out when
>   to goOnline / goOffline to minimize that number.
>
> At the very high end (huge Enterprise apps with 10k+ concurrents) we
>   do offer custom pricing that has a lower per-concurrent rate.

A user benchmarking and testing of connections here on SO: [How the Connection is calculated in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466522/how-the-connection-is-calculated-in-firebase/20663071#20663071)

Another similar question here on SO: [How are concurrent connections calculated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307341/how-exactly-are-concurrent-users-determined-for-a-firebase-app/14307743#14307743)

Comment: Firebase updates its pricing model as of may 18 2016. Now it have 3 Plans Spark, Flame  and Blaze. Spark is free, Flame is 25$/month (for predictable pricing ) and Blaze ( Pay as you go ). See new pricing model https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Comment: +1 for concurrent vs total installs/visits scenario. It was very hard to estimate without the example number.

Comment: Can someone please clarify: what does it exactly mean by 'simultaneous connections'? Is it concurrent users that are logged on at a single time or rather the subscriptions opened by each user at a given time. So for example, say a user goes to my app and opens a page and on that page, there are say 5 subscriptions that are left open until the user leaves the page. Would that count as 5 simultaneous connections or just 1. Either number of subscriptions per user or number of concurrent users in-app?

Comment: See the [FAQ](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#pricing) re: "simultaneous connections". It's the number of open connections to the server.

Comment: My app have max 150 users simultaneously, but still usage charts showing me that 100 limit is reached. My app uses single value listener once per day. I don't understand how this documentation could be truthful