# Firebase concurrent connections?

Tags: firebase

I came across a post [Concurrent firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070095/clarify-the-firebase-connections)

As per top answer on the post if a **user John come online at 12:00 , stay online for 24 hours** , **user Mike come online at 12:01 , stay online for 24 hours** , **user Jack come online at 12:02 , stay only for 24 hours,** Then firebase have only **1 concurrent connection in 24 hours**.

Did I understand correctly?

I was confused because I was thinking concurrent connection means connections to server at a time but as per **explanation above concurrent connections mean connections start at same time**?

Comment: The answer is as clear as it can be, but somehow you mis-interpreted it completely. In your scenario there are 3 users connect from 12:02 on, so you have 3 concurrent connections. But if that answer and the ones that Kato links to in the next answer to the same question doesn't make it clear, I would recommend just writing some code, opening a few browser windows and checking your Firebase dashboard. It is quite easy to see how each concurrent browser window leads to one another concurrent connection in the dashboard, while closing/reopening a tab doesn't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clarify the Firebase connections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070095/clarify-the-firebase-connections)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen : My Mistake I read 5 seconds to 5 minutes .. and it changed all meaning . :)

Comment: Furthermore, users don't stay on a typical page for 24 hours, or even hours, even if it has real-time data (e.g. Twitter). This is particularly true in the mobile world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea how you got from that [accepted answer by @MikePugh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21071014/209103) to your conclusions. The text:

> Concurrent connections are just that - connections established at the same time. So if you have 3 people using your app to check scores, but user 1's app goes online at 12:00 PM **and the connection lasts for 5 seconds**, then user 2's app goes online at 12:01 PM **for 5 seconds**, and user 3's app goes online at 12:02 PM **for 5 seconds** then you've only ever had 1 concurrent connection.

I added emphasis on the parts that you seem to have skipped in your copy.

In the example Mike gave, each user was connected only for a very short time. So there was never more than a single concurrent connection. In fact, for the majority of the day (23 hours 59 minutes 45 seconds) there were 0 connections. Given that Firebase bills at the 95th percentile, you'd be billed for 0 concurrent connections (if they'd offer such a tier).

You indicate that your users stay connected for 24 hours, which leads to 3 concurrent connections from 12:02 to midnight. So you'd have 3 concurrent connections for the majority of the time.

Comment: @All : Yeah sorry .. I read 5 seconds to 5 minutes .. I got it :)