# Clarification on Firebase Cloud Messaging "simultaneous connections"?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Just been doing a bit of research on the different ways to send/receive remote notifications and many answers suggested GCM (now FCM). From what I can understand, this seems feasible for a small scale app that can support 100 online users (free) or 10k users (paid). But I fail to see how it is feasible for a background type notification system which, to be frank, are expected of most apps these days.

Hypothetically, if an app has 1mil users, then there will need to be 1mil simultaneous connections sitting in the background for the notification to reach its user in a timely fashion.

Or am I misinterpreting the "simultaneous" part? When does it apply?

Their FAQ doesn't go into too much details [here](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/#faq-simultaneous).

Comment: You've probably already seen this, but in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070095/clarify-the-firebase-connections they talk about brief polling in the background, which might be helpful to you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit on "simultaneous database connection" refers the usage of the database API.

To receive notifications (whether the app is in background, open, or closed doesn't matter) through FCM (or GCM is the same) your app doesn't need to keep any connection open.

The firebase SDK together with the each platform operative system will take care of that.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Hopefully this will help other newbs.