# Can Firebase's cap of 10000 simultaneous connections support an app that has a sudden burst of 3M connections on a day?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know similar questions about Firebase's simultaneous connections were asked before. The answers were generic and do not apply to the very specific situation that this question discusses.

The official documentation says,
"There is an initial 10,000 simultaneous-connections cap on the Flame and Blaze plans."

https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

I am wondering if this cap might prevent my app from working properly: Suppose I have an app for the upcoming US presidential election. It's going to let users cast a virtual vote and monitor the trend in real time.

Obviously, it's very easy to have more than 10,000 users using the app at the same time (because everyone wants to know who's winning/losing in real time).

The current U.S. population is 320M. Assuming 1% of the population will be using the app on the election day, 3M users will connect to the Firebase database at the same time, constantly keeping an eye on the latest trend.

With this context, can anyone (preferably from Google) clarify if this cap will prevent the voting app from functioning properly? If so, what's the workaround?

Thanks very much.

Hashtag: #AskFirebase

Comment: See this answer for how we calculate concurrent/simultaneous connections: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307341/how-exactly-are-concurrent-users-determined-for-a-firebase-app. The [FAQ on the pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) also explains this (although in less detail). It also contains what to do if you expect to exceed the 10K limit, reach out to support with at least 24 hours notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **simultaneous connections** are if you have 2 devices and first one connected  at 9am for 1min and second one connected at 9:01am for 1 min you have a 1 concurrent connection in 9.00am and in 9.01am but if both connected to 9.00am for 1min you have a 2 concurrent connections... You can learn more about this, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21071014/3996257) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307341/how-exactly-are-concurrent-users-determined-for-a-firebase-app). Greetings!