# Confusion about concurrent connections

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As already stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070095/clarify-the-firebase-connections), I got a question regarding the concurrent connections. In the documentation is stated, that values can (and mostly should) be retreived with `ref.on('child_added')`

Let's say we have a simple list of friends. Does this mean we have one active connection for said callback and additionally another one for the 'child_removed' event (when someone removes me from their friend list).
So we need two callbacks for every data I want to retreive.

This will result in a lot of connections considering things like chat-messages, profile data, and so on, are solved the same way.

Am i misunderstanding the concept,or does this mean that for the 100 free concurrent connections, the limit in a simple chat-application is reached with about 20 users ?

Comment: `.on` will be called on **all** actions. So the callback will be triggered for adding, deleting and updating.

Comment: @camden_kid you mean .on('value',..), right ?

Comment: Yes, ref.on('value'...)

Comment: @camden_kid but that would imply, all the Data is rertreived with every event. This is even worse, Since 'value' returns the entire Data, not juat the one that changes iirc

Comment: That's true. It suits my purpose but I can see it being a problem with large sets of data. It may be better to update locally and use `.once` to get the initial data. There may be a better way with Firebase though I haven't come across it.

Comment: *firebaser here* A single client (browser tab or app instance) keeps at most a single open connection to the Firebase Database servers. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14307743/209103

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen thats super neat. Thanks for the answer.