# Firebase connections mean

Tags: firebase

After reading this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466522/how-the-connection-is-calculated-in-firebase) I still not very clear.

I use `Candle` plan for my example.

If every user in my app have 1 browser tab open mean I can only have 200 users in the same time?

Comment: Yes. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14307743/1266600. "A concurrent user is a single client (browser tab, Node.js process, etc) connected to Firebase at a time. If you have 3 browser tabs open, you should see 3 concurrent users"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How exactly are concurrent users determined for a Firebase app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307341/how-exactly-are-concurrent-users-determined-for-a-firebase-app)

Answer (score 2):

If you're running the free plan, firebase will cut you off at 50 connections.  This means, user 51 will be unable to connect to firebase.  Or, if you open 50 tabs that are all identified as unique firebase connections, tab 51 will not connect.

If you're using any paid plan, your connections will expand and scale automatically, this means that users will never be cut off.

"Because we use 95th percentile billing, you won't be charged for your overages 5% of the time (about 1.5 days each month). If you exceed your limits for more than 5% of the month, the following overage fees will be added to the base price of your monthly bill:"

So, even if you exceed your number of active connections, it will not count for billing unless the number of active connections exceeded your maximum for over 5% of the time covered in the billing period.

Any paid plan will never be cut off (as long as you continue to pay your bills and overages!) so you can have more than 200 users simultaneously!

Source: [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/pricing.html)

Comment: This sounds very dangerous --- if you get DDOS'ed you may incur massive overages very quickly. Surely it should be possible to set a budget.