# How is a "database connection" defined in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

There's a description of what a simultaneous database connection in Firebase is here - https://firebase.google.com/pricing/#faq-simultaneous - but I'm still not totally sure how a connection is defined.

If there's 1 person logged in to Firebase on my app and he's listening for changes on 10 different paths in my real time database, does that count as 11 simultaneous connections?

Comment: A single app on a single device in a single process will be a single connection. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307341/how-exactly-are-concurrent-users-determined-for-a-firebase-app, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466522/how-the-connection-is-calculated-in-firebase, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070095/clarify-the-firebase-connections, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22582395/firebase-connections-mean

Comment: So database connections are the same as concurrent users?!

Comment: Yes. We're hoping the new term will lead to less confusion.

Comment: Why does it say "finished with status: 'connection error'" if I do too many simultaneous database connections (from a single request)?