# does firebase pool connections or create multiple sockets for each reference?

Tags: firebase

If I add dozens of Firebase references using the ios sdk, does it pool or create multiple sockets or does it instead just add more observers to the same socket connection?

e.g. create a bunch of these references

```
var ref = Firebase(url:"https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/web/saving-data/fireblog/posts")
var ref = Firebase(url:"https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/web/saving-data/fireblog/posts2")
..etc.
```

and create an observer for each reference

Will this create multiple connections?  Do I have to worry about performance if I open dozens of these observers?

Comment: Firebase uses a single (Websocket) connection for each open browser tab/window. References are a lightweight mechanism on top of that single connection. This question has been asked before, so I'll vote to close it as a duplicate once I find the original.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How the Connection is calculated in Firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466522/how-the-connection-is-calculated-in-firebase)