# Firebase requests stalling at negotiation phase - how to debug?

Tags: cordova, firebase, ionic-framework

I am working on a phonegap app / crosswalk / ionic app - and on android device some queries get stalled in the websocket negotiation phase without any apparent reason! I just hit the device back button to see some requests get cancelled in the console log and then the rest loads!

Question: what could cause requests to stall at 101 / websocket neogtiation phase. Only some requests stall - others work well - and this is only on android 4.4 - on chrome / mac it works well.

On the same network same app built for iOS works without any network issues.

What could I test to find out what is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How the Connection is calculated in Firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466522/how-the-connection-is-calculated-in-firebase)

Comment: All Firebase traffic from a single browser tab goes through a single connection. This has been asked before, so I marked your question as a duplicate instead of repeating the existing answer. For your other problem you can open a new question, but nobody can help unless you provide enough information. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case the issue was due to commenting out of cordova.js as suggested by ionic-service-deploy documentation.

Uncommenting that, ensures smooth WS connectivity to Firebase. Why it should be such is beyond me - but I have tested by repeatedly adding and removing the include in my index.html to have the effect consistently reproduced on Android/4.4.4 device.

Hope this is of help to others - I spent a large time finding this out!